# Input Icon in a search bar

Tags: vue.js, input, icons

I am trying to input a search icon in the search bar. This is my code that I have used, but the icon is outside the input bar. I would like it to be inside the on the rightmost side.

```
                    <div class="search">
                    <i class="el-icon-search"></i>
                    <el-input placeholder="Search term"></el-input></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should give a style for the icon , such as

```css
i{
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
}
```